# regex: get all of a single character, but not when between single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need a Regex expression to catch all colons in a string, but not when the colon is between single quotes, and then replace it with an at sign (@).

My test string is:

```
select id, :DATA_INI, ':DATA_INI', titulo, date_format(data_criacao,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') str_data_criacao
from v$sugestoes
where data_criacao between :DATA_INI AND :DATA_FIM
order by data_criacao
```

What I actually want is:

```
select id, @DATA_INI, ':DATA_FIM', titulo, date_format(data_criacao,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') str_data_criacao
from v$sugestoes
where data_criacao between @DATA_INI AND @DATA_FIM
order by data_criacao
```

I've tried this regex expression, but for some reason it doesn't catch the first colon:

```
/(?!'.*?):(?!.*?')/g
```

[image]
PS: there's a possibility of nested quotes and these strings can't be catched as well.

Anyone knows what I am missing here? I´m actually using C#.

Comment: What's the regex flavor? Does it support look-behinds?

Comment: This can be better handled with the language means. What is the language you are using? Also, what is your definition of a string inside `''`? Have a look at [`('(?=\S)[^']*\S')|:`](https://regex101.com/r/aY1tL9/1) - this can be used with a callback inside some `Regex.Replace` function.

Comment: And you say `and then replace it with an at sign (@).`  Replacement isn't a function of regular expressions, it gets done by your programming language, using regex to find what needs to be replaced. Per @ClasG's comment, please include more details. This question isn't yet complete enough for us to provide an answer that we know will work for you.

Comment: I'll just use a Regex.Replace later when I have the expression that fits to it. I'd added C# tag but it's not here, so I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could do it:

```
:(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

[RegEx tester](https://regex101.com/r/yK3aN3/1)

It only matches those colons that have an even number of quotes following it (positive look ahead). This also covers the case where quotes are escaped (for SQL) inside quoted string, as those are preceded by another quote and so keep the quote count even.

As stated in comments, this regex is rather inefficient because it scans some parts of the string multiple times: each time a colon is found, the rest of the string is scanned to see whether the number of (non-escaped) quotes is even.

But for SQL strings, which seems to be the types of strings you deal with, this should not be an issue, they are typically strings that are not extremely long, nor have hundreds of quotes or colons.

#### C# solution

Working from the above idea, you could use the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
        string input = "select id, :DATA_INI, ':DATA_INI', titulo, date_format(data_criacao,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') str_data_criacao\n"
            + "from v$sugestoes\n"
            + "where data_criacao between :DATA_INI AND :DATA_FIM AND ':TEST'\n"
            + "  and  'test ''string :DATA_INI '' :DATA_INI '\n"
            + "order by data_criacao";

        string output = Regex.Replace(input, ":(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)", "@");

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

See it run on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/noj5c2).

Comment: I'd only recommend this expression as a means of last resort as it is highly inefficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I agree. It is a pitty the OP has not provided the programming environment in which he needs this. There would often be a more efficient way to do it with those programming language capabilities.

Comment: My mistake. It is C#.

Comment: @trincot There's a very low possibility of having nested quotes, yet it is possible. One more thing to include in my question.

Comment: I added a C++ solution that also takes into account the possibility of nested (escaped) quotes.

Comment: Did this answer your question, or could you leave a comment?

Comment: @trincot my string is a sql expression, so backslashes don't solve it. To escape sql strings we need to double the single quote, as stated here: stackoverflow.com/a/1586588/1269868. And also, for some reason the behavior of ignoring between single quotes doesn't work after the WHERE clause: https://ideone.com/8sfl9X (look at :TEST). ty.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer to deal with SQL quote-escapes and solve the issue with the last colon. See also https://ideone.com/6D8f0F

Comment: Why it is adding two @@ at the end of string? I think that's what I need but this behavior seems odd.

Comment: Hmm... yep that did not work, and I don't see a way to make this method work in all cases. I updated my answer and removed the second idea I used: I am not sure it can work. With the first idea it does work, so the suggested C# code is now based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C#, try:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!'):(\w+)", "@$1")
```

This will match all placeholders which are not *directly* preceeded by a `'` (negative look behind).

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N43ipM

Comment: Is there a simple way to match all placeholders not _between_ a `'`?

Comment: @Sawd, it would be best if you update your question with an example case: input string and expected matches, please.

Comment: I think my question already has those information. I want to replace all `:` with `@` but not when between (nested) single quotes `''`, as my SELECT string example shows. Your example works pretty good in a scenario like this: `':TEST'` but would fail in a scenario like: `'TEST :TEST'`, as you stated.